# Close/Dismiss NSViewController, macOS

Tags: swift, macos

I have a `NSViewController` connected as such:

[image]

In the bottom viewController, I try to dismiss it using `self.dismiss(self)` however, it produces this error:

```
[General] dismissViewController:: Error: maybe this view controller was not presented?
```

How can I ever dismiss this viewcontroller?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Was the view controller presented? Or do you want to close the window?

Comment: It is the default nsviewcontroller when making a new project. I dont think its presented because I got that error. I am not using a WindowController rather a NSViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I did:

In the presented window (NSViewController) add the following:
Add this to the top of the presented class as a property:

```
class FooViewController: NSViewController {  
// reference to a window  
var window: NSWindow?  
...  
}
```

Add this override of viewDidAppear, not viewDidLoad as the window handle is nil.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {  
    // After a window is displayed, get the handle to the new window.  
    window = self.view.window!  
}
```

2. Now where you currently have "dismissViewController" you can use:

   window?.performClose(nil) // nil because I'm not return a message

Comment: Why do you need the `window` property, is `self.view.window` unavailable when you use the property?